# Interested in VM for lisp-like languages on 8-bit system

Tags: lisp, vm-implementation, 6502, logo-lang

I'm looking for recommended virtual machines that can run on a 8-bit microprocessor AND support dynamic languages.  I'd like a VM solution because I perceive benefits in terms of code density, portability, and ability to have a smaller interpreter, leaving more room for larger programs.

My goal is to run a complete LOGO interpreter, following "LOGO for the Apple II" syntax, on something like a 6502 microprocessor.

I've seen references to [PyMite](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyMite), Java "micro edition", and of course now the UCSD p-System sources from the 1970s are available.

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You can frequently find mini-schemes.

Comment: MakerLisp is a Lisp targeted at embedded systems, which will run on a ez80 processor.

Early versions use a subset of a "full Lisp" (powerpoint link - https://img1.wsimg.com/blobby/go/72a1c0e7-ca37-40c1-a729-18ba8ef5064a/downloads/1d2iiek4h_313558.ppt

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ad9NtyBCx78

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check out the [PICOBIT](https://github.com/stamourv/picobit) system, which is a Scheme implementation that works on very very small systems, such as the PIC18.  It has since been ported to ARM, and could almost certainly be ported to the 6502 or other processors.

Comment: This is my favorite answer, since it gets most directly at the requirement

Answer (score 7):

(Note: I've already +1'ed the FORTH answer.)

Since you mention the 6502, Steve Wozniak (!) wrote an article for Byte magazine in the late 1970s, describing the [SWEET16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWEET16) interpreter for the 6502.  This was a partial VM for the 6502, that provided 16-bit integer arithmetic that was EASILY interspersed into 6502 assembly language.  It was the basis for the original Integer BASIC, that (as I recall) was later replaced by the floating-point Applesoft BASIC.

Answer (score 6):

[FORTH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) [implementation for 6502](http://www.6502.org/source/forth65.zip).